# css last child not working

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have a grid of news articles and I wanting it so the last two articles in the grid do not have a bottom border, however my css `last-child` selector does not seem to be working, the last article with the class right has the border taken off, however the last article with the class left does not, is there a reason for this?

Here is a fiddle of my code and problem.

http://jsfiddle.net/Udders/HJE5h/

Comment: The last `.left` is not the last child of your topmost `div`, so it doesn't match.

Comment: is there a way I could target the last .left and the last .right?

Comment: Not with CSS because of backtracking limitations, but if you could somehow switch the bottom borders for top borders, and use [this technique](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107) to apply the borders and backgrounds, it might work.

Comment: If you can use `:last-child`, can't you just use `:nth-last-child`? They have virtually the same level of browser support. http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/HJE5h/3/

Comment: @thirtydot: It should be possible, but it depends somewhat on the structure of the `.left` and `.right` elements. Looks worth a shot though.

Answer (score 6):

As mentioned by @BoltClock above, swap the `broder-bottom` for `border-top` and target the `first-child` instead. SOme older browsers do not support `last-child`:

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HJE5h/2/**

#### Edit

Ok, as @BoltClock mentions in the comment below, the problem is not entirely with the `last-child` issue. However, if you do use `border-top` as suggested above and then target the next `select` element that directly follows the `first-child`, you can remove `border-top` from the first two articles.

```
section:first-child .snippet, section:first-child + section .snippet {
    background:none;
    border-top:none;
}
```

**JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HJE5h/5/**

Comment: The browser support issue isn't the real cause here, but it's important to know anyway.

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve that by using nth-last-child(n) pseudo class. It begins at the end of the collection and this way you can specify the last two elements without knowing the size of the collection. Please try this selector in your css code:

```
.grid_9:nth-last-child(1) .snippet, .grid_9:nth-last-child(2) .snippet {
    background: none;
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

This is a good reference for useful css selectors http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/